# INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT vs INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG

Tags: windows, proxy, wininet

In this [documentation for InternetOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the MSDN says:

> Use INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT if the system on which the application is running uses a direct connection to the Internet. ...
>
> Use INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY if the system on which the application is running uses one or more proxy servers to access the Internet.
>
> INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG looks at the registry values ProxyEnable, ProxyServer, and ProxyOverride. ... If ProxyEnable is zero, the application uses INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT. Otherwise, the application uses INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY and uses the ProxyServer and ProxyOverride information.

I interpreted this to mean that if you were writing an application where there's any possibility of the user being behind a proxy, you should use `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG`, and Windows will automatically go for the "direct" option if the user isn't behind a proxy.

However, a number of users have run into problems with badly configured Windows installs, which have a bad proxy server configured for some reason. Because we use `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG`, internet access doesn't work for those users. Some of them can resolve the bad configuration, but not all.

Is there any downside to just using `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT` instead of `_PRECONFIG`? It sounds like we should use `_PRECONFIG` if we want to be a good citizen, but we can save ourselves and our users a lot of headaches if we just use `_DIRECT` instead.

Comment: You could use the DIRECT flag and provide your own mechanism for using a proxy.  However, I would think that a bad configuration would cause them problems in other apps.  Internet Explorer is the obvious example, but Firefox used to (and maybe still does?) use that proxy information if it is present.  Other apps that use WinINet, etc.

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but apparently not - our app is apparently the only one using _PRECONFIG, as users say everything else works fine. :(